# Forwarding in BIND DNS failed?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, bind, forwarding

I have BIND working on Windows Server 2003. I want to forward my queries to another server. Recursion is working but forwarding is not working. Can you guide me to set it. I've given the following in the options:

```
options {
    directory "c:\named\zones";
    allow-transfer { none; };
    forward only;
    forwarders { 8.8.8.8 ; };
    recursion no;
};
```

Is the format for forwarding correct in the above?

If not, what is the format? Am I to give any port number in the forwarders line? Does forwarding have any particular port number?

Thank You in advance....

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Forwarding is typically configured for recursive servers but you wrote "recursion no". And you claim that "recursion is working" which I find hard to believe.

Therefore, you should edit your question to mention **actual** tests with dig and their results (not vague sentences such as "forwarding is not working") and to explain what is the goal.